# Characterize the type of sequence that satisfies $\prod (1-a_i) \leq c$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, products, infinite-product

Consider a product $\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-a_i)$ where $n\leq \infty$ and $a_i\in [0,1)$ for all $i$. I'm hoping to see if there exist conditions on the sequence $\{a_i\}$ so that

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-a_i)\leq c.$$

The product can be reduced to $\sum_{B\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}} (-1)^{|B|} \prod_{b\in B} a_b$, but from there it's not clear where to go. Simple limiting convergence results aren't strong enough to address the bound $c$. When $c=0$ and $n=\infty$, this will require that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = \infty$ if I am not mistaken.

I realize this question is very general, so feel free to impose additional assumptions on $\{a_i\}$ if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can take logarithms, then the inequality becomes

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log (1-a_i) \leqslant \log c.\tag{1}$$

Expanding the logarithms in Taylor series,

$$\log (1-x) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}$$

and multiplying with $-1$, it becomes

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_i^k}{k} \geqslant -\log c.\tag{2}$$

Since all terms on the left are non-negative, we can change the order of summation and get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^k \geqslant -\log c.\tag{3}$$

In all this, we can allow $c = 0$ with the small abuse of notation that $\log 0 = -\infty$ and $-\log 0 = +\infty$.

Then we get a chain of sufficient conditions

- $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i \geqslant -\log c$,
- $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \geqslant -\log c$

and so on.

For $c = 0$ the conditions $n = \infty$ and

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = +\infty$$

are necessary and sufficient, for if $\sum a_i$ were finite, then also $\sum \log (1-a_i)$ would be finite, and the product strictly positive.

For $c \geqslant 1$, the inequality is trivially satisfied, and for $0 < c < 1$, $(1),(2),(3)$ are somewhat tautological necessary and sufficient conditions, but the sufficient conditions involving only the finitely many of the power sums may be of the kind you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1,\ldots,n-1}$ be *any* sequence in $[0,1)$. Then you can just define the $n$th term to be large enough so that full product is small enough: $$a_n\geq1-c\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-a_i)^{-1}$$

So if there is no constraint on $n-1$ out of $n$ terms, then is this the right question to ask? Perhaps if the sequence $\{a_i\}$ were required to be decreasing? But then there would be no constraints on the *last* $n-1$ terms, and you could make the first term as large as needed. Putting a constraint on only one term of a sequence but letting the rest of the sequence do whatever it wants doesn't feel like characterizing the sequence in a meaningful way.

If $n=\infty$, these considerations don't quite apply.